# Lookup for a value in a range that has array values and constants mixed within

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was provided data that has an id column that leads to a value.

When two ids lead to the same value they are contained in an array ={...}, otherwise, they are a constant value.

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | A |
| =@{0002,0003} | B |
| 0004 | C |

Looking for the value attributed to the ID 0001 is a straightforward LOOKUP function.
I cannot think of a function that will return the value attributed to an ID contained within an array (i.e. ID 0003).

I'm not allowed to create a new row for every value within the array.

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(VALUE([@CCC]),'Sheet1'!$B$4:$C$541),[Some way of looking within the ids contained within the array])`

```vb
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Integer, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Comment: `=@{0002,0003}` is this the text within the cell?

Comment: @Ike: It's a formula representing an array. You can access it in VBA via `Formula`, but as far as I know not as `Value` (Value will return the first value, eg 2)

Comment: @Ike Thomas Is right, I wrote the formula contained within a cell that represents an array, the actual value would be the first entry of the array: 0002.

Comment: @IBas: out of curiosity: why is it done like this? It seems very weird and **error prone** to have two data in one cell ... What is the reason to not split those values - e.g. on a second sheet?

Comment: @Ike To be honest, it is distributed like this due to the fact that the table is structured according to another set of values that are necessary. The ID field is going to be swapped into ID values that allow for more specific instances and values. However, we have to verify that the old ID system and the new ID system lead up to a similar and correct allocation of data and values. Therefore, the array instances in the id field is a stopgap that I'm not allowed to redesign. I'm not sure if that answers your question but I'm open to give further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Microsoft does not provide a way to get the array in a cell as array. If you access the `Value`-property, you will get the first entry of the array (that's also what is displayed in Excel), so in your case `2`.

Best bet is probably to access the array as string using the `Formula2`-property and do some string gymnastics to create an array out of it.

I played around with it and came up with the following code. I tried to implement handling of strings and numbers. If a cell contains only a single value, it is converted to an array with only one member.

```
Function myArrayLookup(searchValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, col_index As Long) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Intersect(lookupRange, lookupRange.Parent.UsedRange)
        Dim cellValue As Variant
        cellValue = cell.Formula2
        
        Dim tokens() As String
        If Left(cellValue, 3) = "=@{" Then
            cellValue = Mid(cellValue, 4, Len(cellValue) - 4)
            tokens = Split(cellValue, ",")
        Else  ' We deal with a single value
            ReDim tokens(0 To 0)  
            tokens(0) = cell.value
        End If
    
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
            If VarType(searchValue) = vbDouble Then
                ' Numeric comparison
                If Val(searchValue) = Val(tokens(i)) Then
                    myArrayLookup = cell.Offset(0, col_index - 1)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                ' String comparison
                If searchValue = Replace(tokens(i), """", "") Then
                    myArrayLookup = cell.Offset(0, col_index - 1)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
    myArrayLookup = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

You can use it as an UDF or within VBA. Usage is very similar to VLookup (only without the infamous 4th parameter).

If someone tells us a better way to deal with Excel-arrays in VBA, I am glad to upvote (and possibly delete my answer).

Comment: `evaluate(cell.formula2)` would give you an array (1-based)